# How to parse JSON objects that depend on array contents for their attributes with JQ?

Tags: jq

I have this complex array of JSON objects that have attributes that are arrays which may or may not be populated.

I am looking for a way using `jq` to filter out the array elements that do not have any items in their `updates` attribute, but this is buried deep down the object tree.

Is there a way to produce the sample output from the input JSON array under it?

What I am trying to find is:

Select all top level objects from the array that have a `baseBranch` attribute and a non-empty `config` attribute and filter out the results to show me only the elements within the (`gradle` and `gradle-wrapper`) attributes within the `config` that have a non-empty `deps` array attribute. The result is a `deps` element that have a non-empty `updates` array in it.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can take this challenge!

Edit:

- Yes I have tried solving it on my own. I have been through the documentation and so far this is the expression I have: `.[] | . as $parent | select(.baseBranch != null and .config != null) | .config | [.gradle[] .deps[]]`
- This will filter out all the top level elements and get me to the dependency array, but I cannot figure out how to filter out the `deps` array and group them by the attribute where they are located.

Edit 2:

The query bellow is returning most of the information I want. But I'd like to figure out how to group the `updates` by the `repository` and `file` values.

```
jq '.[] 
    | . as $parent 
    | select(.baseBranch != null and .config != null) 
    | .config.gradle[]?.deps[]? as $deps
    | [
        {
            repository: $parent.repository,
            file:$deps.managerData.packageFile, 
            depName:$deps.depName,
            currentVersion:$deps.currentValue,
            newVersion:$deps.updates[]?.newVersion
        }
    ]
'
```

```json
/* Desired sample output */
[
    { 
        "repository": "repositoryName",
        "numberOfUpdates": 5, 
        "gradleUpdates": [
            {
                "fileName": "dependencies.gradle",
                "package": "packageName.api:feature-flags", /* if packageName then display the depName */
                "currentVersion": "0.20.0",
                "newVersion": "0.21.0"
            },
            {
                "fileName": "dependencies.gradle",
                "package": "io.rest-assured:xml-path", /* if packageName then display the depName */
                "currentVersion": "4.5.1",
                "newVersion": "5.1.1"
            },
            {
                "fileName": "build.gradle",
                "package": "com.diffplug.spotless:com.diffplug.spotless.gradle.plugin", /* if packageName then display the depName */
                "currentVersion": "6.9.0",
                "newVersion": "6.10.0"
            },
            {
                "fileName": "build.gradle",
                "package": "org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin", /* if packageName then display the depName */
                "currentVersion": "2.7.2",
                "newVersion": "2.7.3"
            }
        ],
        "gradleWrapperUpdates": [
            {
                "fileName": "gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties",
                "currentVersion": "7.5",
                "newVersion": "7.5.1"
            }
        ]
    }
]


/* This is the input */
[
    {
        "randomKey": "this is not what I am looking for",
        "otherFields": "other object that does not match the query"
    },
    {
        "repository": "myRepositoryName",
        "baseBranch": "master",
        "config": {
            "gradle": [
                {
                    "packageFile": "gradle.properties",
                    "datasource": "maven",
                    "deps": []
                },
                {
                    "packageFile": "dependencies.gradle",
                    "datasource": "maven",
                    "deps": [
                        {
                            "depName": "packageName:dependencyName",
                            "currentValue": "0.8.0",
                            "managerData": {
                                "fileReplacePosition": 611,
                                "packageFile": "dependencies.gradle"
                            },
                            "fileReplacePosition": 611,
                            "registryUrls": [
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/release",
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/maven-mirror",
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/gradle-plugins"
                            ],
                            "depType": "dependencies",
                            "depIndex": 0,
                            "updates": [],
                            "warnings": [],
                            "versioning": "gradle",
                            "currentVersion": "0.8.0",
                            "fixedVersion": "0.8.0"
                        },
                        {
                            "depName": "packageName.api:feature-flags",
                            "currentValue": "0.20.0",
                            "managerData": {
                                "fileReplacePosition": 1118,
                                "packageFile": "dependencies.gradle"
                            },
                            "fileReplacePosition": 1118,
                            "registryUrls": [
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/release",
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/maven-mirror",
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/gradle-plugins"
                            ],
                            "depType": "dependencies",
                            "depIndex": 8,
                            "updates": [
                                {
                                    "bucket": "non-major",
                                    "newVersion": "0.21.0",
                                    "newValue": "0.21.0",
                                    "releaseTimestamp": "2022-08-25T04:57:50.000Z",
                                    "newMajor": 0,
                                    "newMinor": 21,
                                    "updateType": "minor",
                                    "branchName": "renovate/all-minor-patch"
                                }
                            ],
                            "warnings": [],
                            "versioning": "gradle",
                            "currentVersion": "0.20.0",
                            "isSingleVersion": true,
                            "fixedVersion": "0.20.0"
                        },
                        {
                            "depName": "io.rest-assured:xml-path",
                            "currentValue": "4.5.1",
                            "managerData": {
                                "fileReplacePosition": 3307,
                                "packageFile": "dependencies.gradle"
                            },
                            "fileReplacePosition": 3307,
                            "registryUrls": [
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/release",
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/maven-mirror",
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/gradle-plugins"
                            ],
                            "depType": "dependencies",
                            "depIndex": 39,
                            "updates": [
                                {
                                    "bucket": "major",
                                    "newVersion": "5.1.1",
                                    "newValue": "5.1.1",
                                    "releaseTimestamp": "2022-06-10T06:46:14.000Z",
                                    "newMajor": 5,
                                    "newMinor": 1,
                                    "updateType": "major",
                                    "branchName": "renovate/io.rest-assured-xml-path-5.x"
                                }
                            ],
                            "warnings": [],
                            "versioning": "gradle",
                            "sourceUrl": "http://svn.sonatype.org/spice/tags/oss-parent-5",
                            "homepage": "https://rest-assured.io/",
                            "currentVersion": "4.5.1",
                            "isSingleVersion": true,
                            "fixedVersion": "4.5.1"
                        },
                        {
                            "depName": "io.rest-assured:json-schema-validator",
                            "currentValue": "5.1.1",
                            "managerData": {
                                "fileReplacePosition": 3376,
                                "packageFile": "dependencies.gradle"
                            },
                            "fileReplacePosition": 3376,
                            "registryUrls": [
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/release",
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/maven-mirror",
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/gradle-plugins"
                            ],
                            "depType": "dependencies",
                            "depIndex": 40,
                            "updates": [],
                            "warnings": [],
                            "versioning": "gradle",
                            "sourceUrl": "http://svn.sonatype.org/spice/tags/oss-parent-5",
                            "homepage": "http://maven.apache.org",
                            "currentVersion": "5.1.1",
                            "fixedVersion": "5.1.1"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "packageFile": "settings.gradle",
                    "datasource": "maven",
                    "deps": []
                },
                {
                    "packageFile": "build.gradle",
                    "datasource": "maven",
                    "deps": [
                        {
                            "depType": "plugin",
                            "depName": "com.diffplug.spotless",
                            "packageName": "com.diffplug.spotless:com.diffplug.spotless.gradle.plugin",
                            "registryUrls": [
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/release",
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/maven-mirror",
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/gradle-plugins",
                                "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
                            ],
                            "commitMessageTopic": "plugin com.diffplug.spotless",
                            "currentValue": "6.9.0",
                            "managerData": {
                                "fileReplacePosition": 50,
                                "packageFile": "build.gradle"
                            },
                            "fileReplacePosition": 50,
                            "depIndex": 0,
                            "updates": [
                                {
                                    "bucket": "non-major",
                                    "newVersion": "6.10.0",
                                    "newValue": "6.10.0",
                                    "releaseTimestamp": "2022-08-24T14:40:44.000Z",
                                    "newMajor": 6,
                                    "newMinor": 10,
                                    "updateType": "minor",
                                    "branchName": "renovate/all-minor-patch"
                                }
                            ],
                            "warnings": [],
                            "versioning": "gradle",
                            "currentVersion": "6.9.0",
                            "isSingleVersion": true,
                            "fixedVersion": "6.9.0"
                        },
                        {
                            "depType": "plugin",
                            "depName": "docker-publish-convention",
                            "packageName": "docker-publish-convention:docker-publish-convention.gradle.plugin",
                            "registryUrls": [
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/release",
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/maven-mirror",
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/gradle-plugins",
                                "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
                            ],
                            "commitMessageTopic": "plugin docker-publish-convention",
                            "currentValue": "latest.release",
                            "managerData": {
                                "fileReplacePosition": 158,
                                "packageFile": "build.gradle"
                            },
                            "fileReplacePosition": 158,
                            "depIndex": 2,
                            "updates": [],
                            "warnings": [],
                            "versioning": "gradle",
                            "skipReason": "invalid-value"
                        },
                        {
                            "depType": "plugin",
                            "depName": "org.springframework.boot",
                            "packageName": "org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin",
                            "registryUrls": [
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/release",
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/maven-mirror",
                                "https://mavenCentral/repository/gradle-plugins",
                                "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
                            ],
                            "commitMessageTopic": "plugin org.springframework.boot",
                            "currentValue": "2.7.2",
                            "managerData": {
                                "fileReplacePosition": 217,
                                "packageFile": "build.gradle"
                            },
                            "fileReplacePosition": 217,
                            "depIndex": 3,
                            "updates": [
                                {
                                    "bucket": "non-major",
                                    "newVersion": "2.7.3",
                                    "newValue": "2.7.3",
                                    "releaseTimestamp": "2022-08-18T06:30:12.000Z",
                                    "newMajor": 2,
                                    "newMinor": 7,
                                    "updateType": "patch",
                                    "branchName": "renovate/all-minor-patch"
                                }
                            ],
                            "warnings": [],
                            "versioning": "gradle",
                            "sourceUrl": "https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot",
                            "homepage": "https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot",
                            "currentVersion": "2.7.2",
                            "isSingleVersion": true,
                            "fixedVersion": "2.7.2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "gradle-wrapper": [
                {
                    "packageFile": "gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties",
                    "deps": [
                        {
                            "depName": "gradle",
                            "currentValue": "7.5",
                            "replaceString": "https\\://mavenCentral/repository/gradle-dist/gradle-7.5-bin.zip",
                            "datasource": "gradle-version",
                            "versioning": "gradle",
                            "depIndex": 0,
                            "updates": [
                                {
                                    "bucket": "non-major",
                                    "newVersion": "7.5.1",
                                    "newValue": "7.5.1",
                                    "releaseTimestamp": "2022-08-05T21:17:56.000Z",
                                    "newMajor": 7,
                                    "newMinor": 5,
                                    "updateType": "patch",
                                    "branchName": "renovate/all-minor-patch"
                                }
                            ],
                            "warnings": [],
                            "sourceUrl": "https://github.com/gradle/gradle",
                            "homepage": "https://gradle.org",
                            "currentVersion": "7.5",
                            "isSingleVersion": true,
                            "fixedVersion": "7.5"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some assumptions made for the edge cases, this should meet your requirements:

```bash
map(select(has("baseBranch") and .config != {}) | {
  repository,
  numberOfUpdates: 0,
  gradleUpdates: .config.gradle,
  gradleWrapperUpdates: .config."gradle-wrapper"
} | (.gradleUpdates, .gradleWrapperUpdates) |= map(
  .packageFile as $fileName | .deps[] | .updates[] as $update | {
    $fileName,
    package: (.packageName // .depName),
    currentVersion,
    newVersion: $update.newValue
  })
  | .numberOfUpdates += ([.gradleUpdates, .gradleWrapperUpdates | length] | add)
)
```

```json
[
  {
    "repository": "myRepositoryName",
    "numberOfUpdates": 5,
    "gradleUpdates": [
      {
        "fileName": "dependencies.gradle",
        "package": "packageName.api:feature-flags",
        "currentVersion": "0.20.0",
        "newVersion": "0.21.0"
      },
      {
        "fileName": "dependencies.gradle",
        "package": "io.rest-assured:xml-path",
        "currentVersion": "4.5.1",
        "newVersion": "5.1.1"
      },
      {
        "fileName": "build.gradle",
        "package": "com.diffplug.spotless:com.diffplug.spotless.gradle.plugin",
        "currentVersion": "6.9.0",
        "newVersion": "6.10.0"
      },
      {
        "fileName": "build.gradle",
        "package": "org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin",
        "currentVersion": "2.7.2",
        "newVersion": "2.7.3"
      }
    ],
    "gradleWrapperUpdates": [
      {
        "fileName": "gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties",
        "package": "gradle",
        "currentVersion": "7.5",
        "newVersion": "7.5.1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WjO3PRCKTm6)

Comment: You are a legend, thank you!